# How to overwrite datasource of rpx file for active reports in c#?

Tags: c#, datasource, overwrite, activereports

I have a rpx file with a datasource by default. I want to load it and check if the user wants to use a different datasource. I´ve already overwritten the datasource of the SectionReport object and execute a reader before to send it for loadlayout method. Do I need to map the fields with the textboxes or am I missing something for changing the datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new datasource has different fields (columns) that the original datasource, then you'll need to add fields in the Fields collection of the report and also change the DataField property of the TextBoxes to the new fields in order to display new data. Take a look at the 'To use an Unbound data source' topic at the following documentation link: http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR11/index.html#BindReportstoaDataSource.html

Edit:
You can change just the connection string of the report's DataSource in the following way:

```
SectionReport rpt = new SectionReport();
XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader("../../Invoice1.rpx");
rpt.LoadLayout(xtr);            

var dataSource = rpt.DataSource as GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Data.OleDBDataSource;
dataSource.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =C:\BILL.mdb; Persist Security Info = False";

rpt.Run();

viewer1.LoadDocument(rpt);
```

Comment: Other question actually what I really need is too change just the connection string is possible to overwrite just the connection string of the file.?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ActiveReport_ReportStart()
    Dim total as Integer
    'Set data source connection string.
    m_cnnString = "Data Source=#######################;"
    'Set data source SQL query.
    sqlString = "SELECT * FROM products"
    'Open connection and create DataReader.
    m_cnn = New SqlConnection(m_cnnString)
    Dim m_Cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", m_cnn)
    If m_cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        m_cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = m_Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while reader.read() 
        total+=Convert.toInt32(reader.Item("QuantityPerUnit").ToString())
    End While
    reader.close()
    Me.txtCR.Text=total.ToString()
    rpt.DataSource = m_Cmd.ExecuteReader()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).